# how to Load Helpers in Codeigniter on Linux machine?

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: see this]i was working on Codeigniter Application in WAMP and then i had to move my project to a LINUX machine.

Now When i have installed LAMP there. but When i try to access my application i get an error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/url_helper.php

i checked my autoload.php. This worked on my windows don't why its not working here.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html','crm_helper','form');
```

Can you please guide me where i am going wrong?

Comment: which one is not working add one by one and check

Comment: Did you copy the folders from Windows to Linux or is it a fresh installation from download?

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't have the **crm_helper** in the correct path, or you don't have it at all.

Comment: once i remove any helper from the autoload it start pointing to other helper for error @saurabhkamble

Comment: @itsols i removed crm_helper from my autoload still doesnt works

Comment: @Rajan add that error in the question

Comment: i already have its just shows me Unable to load the requested file: helpers/url_helper.php

Comment: i have added the screen shot see @saurabhkamble

Comment: @Rajan your are using url function and you not auto-loaded url helper now just add url helper in it

Comment: @saurabhkamble so i should manually load the url helper? or shall i put it in autload.php?

Comment: @Rajan try both ways

Comment: tried both @saurabhkamble but i think there is some reconfiguration in my installation so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98536/discussion-between-saurabh-kamble-and-rajan).

Comment: Use master version instead of develop one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your modified question, it seems that you are in fact missing the url_helper in your autoload line. It should be like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html','url_helper','form');
```

Also include the *exact* version of codeigniter that you've installed, in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me ! on my local windows system it was fine ,but when i migrated to Linux server (my hosting server )then it generate the same error: it was due to case-sensitivity of Linux.

these are two deffrent words in linux: 
'crm_helper'
'Crm_helper'

> so i suggest you to check your files name , 
>   Linux system crm_helper and Crm_helper are two different files.
>   remove _helper while loading any helper file / code